# How can I show the parameters in the URL when using Datatables' Server-side processing and SearchBuilder with Django?

Tags: django, datatables, server-side

I created a Django web app that queries a very large database. To address that, I use Datatables with Server-side processing and SearchBuilder and Django Pagination which all works great. I have an "index" view for a landing page which includes a Datatables component.  A serperate "dt-json" view is used to respond to the Datatables' ajax request with json data. I need the index page to have the ajax request parameters as endpoints in the URL. Currently, the index page URL looks like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and I want it to look like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=id&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&col... by default, with the entire SearchBuilder parameter string as the endpoint for bookmarking purposes. I know that the index page is not receiving the ajax request but is there a simple way of passing up this data to be displayed in the index URL?

This is my first question post on Stack Overflow so my apoligies for any discrepancies.
Thanks SO!

Snippets of my code.
models.py:

```
class Flight(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'flight'

    def get_data(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'user': self.user,
        }
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # homepage
    path('', views.index, name='landing-page'),

    # JSON object URL for datatables query.
    path('dt-json/', views.dt_json, name='dt-json'),
]
```

index view:

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def index(request):
    cur_user = request.user
    context = {
        'cur_user': cur_user,
        }
    return render(request, 'flight_deck/index.html', context)
```

dt-json view:

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def dt_json(request):

    ###
    Ommitted a lot of logic here for brevity and security.
    Mostly converting the request into a dict and then filtering the query into a query_set
    ###

    # use django paginator to filter all flights into flight pages
    paginator = Paginator(query_set, limit) # Show 'length' flights per page
    page = offset  # define the first page offest index
    table_page = paginator.get_page(page) # Collect one page of flights as an object

    # Datatables uses draw, recordsTotal, and recordsFiltered for processing JSON data
    draw = request.GET.get('draw')
    recordsTotal = model.objects.count()
    recordsFiltered = query_size
    data = json_data

    # Generate datatables JSON object
    response = {
        "draw": draw,
        "recordsTotal": recordsTotal,
        "recordsFiltered": recordsFiltered,
        "data": data,
    }
    return JsonResponse(response)
```

index.html

```
{% extends "./base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Welcome to the APEX Job Manager, {{ cur_user.first_name }}</h2>
    <h4>Recent Flights</h4>
    {% include "./components/flight_table.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

flight_table.html

```
{% block flight_table %}
<table id="flight-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>User</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<script>
    var datatableColumnDefinitions = [
        {data: "id"},
        {data: "user"},
    ]
    var ajaxUrl = "dt-json/"
    var datatableOptions = {
        searching: false,
        paging: true,
        lengthMenu: [5, 10, 25, 50, 100],
        pageLength: 10,
        serverSide: true,
        processing: true,
        scrollX: true,
        order: [[ 0, 'desc' ]],
        ajax: {
            url: ajaxUrl,
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                table: 'flight'
            }
        },
        columns: datatableColumnDefinitions,
        dom: 'Qlfrtip',
        searchBuilder: {}
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#flight-table').DataTable(datatableOptions);
        // makes each table row a clickable link to the flight detail page
        $('#flight-table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var data = table.row(this).data();
            window.location.href="flight/"+data.id;
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: A suggestion: Take a look at how to create a [mre] - and remove all code which is not relevant to the _very specific_ question you are asking. Currently, your question looks as if you have just thrown all your code at us (maybe that is unfair of me...). "_I need the index page to have the ajax request parameters as endpoints_" - Are you familiar with query parameters and how they work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @andrewJames
I need to remove/hide a lot of code because it is proprietary. I posted what I could to understand file structure and functionality. I am familiar with how those work but I am new to Django. I know that in urls.py you can define expected params using "url<type:data>" notation but when using datatables, it is all handled on the front end it seems. Is there a better way to structure the dt-json function to handle this request?

Comment: "_I need to remove/hide a lot of code because it is proprietary_" - You probably need to provide a lot *less* code than you are currently providing (I suggest). See [mre]. It seems that your question is basically "_how do I handle request parameters in Django (or, if I use `POST` instead of `GET`, how do I handle the request body)?_" If this is what you are actually asking then focus on that. If it's not what you are asking then my apologies, I have missed the point of your question.